# Cannot get webpack-dev-server (webpack) to produce a sourcemap in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This has worked for me in the past using manual webpack but for any react project now i cant seem to get a sourcemap in the dev tools using webpack-dev-server no matter what config i use. ive tried several devtools values including 'source-map'. I just see 'add files to workspace' instead of 'sourcemap detected' - any ideas?

chrome version Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit) (mac)

- Developer Tools Experiments flag is enabled

  - [image]

webpack version 1.13.2
webpack.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map', 
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }]
  },
}
```

[image: dev tools - no sourcemap]

Answer (score 1):

finally figured this out - turns out this was a babel loader config issue. Adding a query param to the babel loader block allowed me to produce source maps:

```
/* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname,
      //here
      query: {
        retainLines: true,
        cacheDirectory: true
      }
    }]
  },
}
```